# How to parse the text into specific array list?

Tags: javascript, regex

I've got the the following string:

```
const text = '01. is simply dummy text of the printing. 02. It is a long established fact that a reader will be. 03. and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum.';
```

I need to parse it out into the following array list:

```
[
  '01. is simply dummy text of the printing.',
  '02. It is a long established fact that a reader will be.',
  '03. and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum.'
]
```

I've tried this approach, but don't get desired result:

```
const list = text.match(/\d+.\s(.*)./g);

[
  '01. is simply dummy text of the printing. 02. It is a long established fact that a reader will be. 03. and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum.'
]
```

Kindly ask you help me me out with it.

Comment: Did you mean like this? `\d+\.\s.*?\.(?= |$)` https://regex101.com/r/uonAPR/1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
/\d+\..*?\.(?=\s*\d+\.|$)/g
/\d+\.[\s\S]*?\.(?=\s*\d+\.|$)/g
```

See the [**regex demo online**](https://regex101.com/r/5pZrpL/1). The `[\s\S]` regex version will match multiline chunks of text (use if needed).

**Details**

- `\d+` - 1+ digits
- `\.` - a dot (must be escaped)
- `.*?` - any 0 or more chars other than line break chars (if you use `[\s\S]` it will also match line breaks) as few as possible
- `\.` - a dot...
- `(?=\s*\d+\.|$)` - that is followed with 0+ whitespaces, 1+ digits and a dot or end of string.

See JS demo:

```js
const text = '01. is simply dummy text of the printing. 02. It is a long established fact that a reader will be. 03. and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum.';
console.log(text.match(/\d+\..*?\.(?=\s*\d+\.|$)/g));
```

Answer (score 2):

You could match the digits followed by a dot up until the first occurrence of a dot followed by either a whitespace char or the end of the string.

```
\d+\.\s.*?\.(?=\s|$)
```

*Explanation*

- `\d+` Match 1+ digits
- `\.\s.*?\.` Match the dot and as least as possible chars until the next dot
- `(?=\s|$)` Positive lookahead, assert what follows is either a whitespace char or end of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/t2MAa7/1)

```js
const text = '01. is simply dummy text of the printing. 02. It is a long established fact that a reader will be. 03. and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum.';
pattern = /\d+\.\s.*?\.(?=\s|$)/g;
console.log(text.match(pattern));
```

Answer (score 1):

If we can assume that there's no digits inside the sentences, you could look for anything that doesn't contain a digit and ends with a fullstop.

Also a `.` in regex means "match anything", if you want a proper full stop, you need to escape it `\.`

```js
const text = '01. is simply dummy text of the printing. 02. It is a long established fact that a reader will be. 03. and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum.';

const list = text.match(/(\d+\.[^\d]+\.)/g);

console.log(list)
```